# How to print the build target in Java?

Tags: java, ant, build, build-process

Say we have a class PrintTarget with main() inside of it.

Can we build/compile such that , somehow we should be able to send the build-target-name inside of the main.  and when the main() is called it will print the  build-target name.

I dont want the target name  WHILE building.  we all know how to do that.
I want the generated JAR to remember the target name. 
Say we  created the jar     printTarget.jar
And executed the jar  #>java   printTarget.jar
I want this invocation to print the   target name.

Comment: Do you relay mean build target? What do you understand under that term. I understan the "jar-target" the "the compile-target", the "clean-target", the "java-doc target". All contained in a build system / skript.

Comment: Is it an argument you want to print while running your class e.g.  `java PrintTarget buildtarget1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass data from build time to run time you need to write the data into a file that is stored in the JAR, e.g.

```
<jar destfile="printTarget.jar">
  <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" />
  <manifest>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.example.Main" />
  </manifest>
  <!-- This is just a way to create a zip entry from inline text in the build
       file without having to <echo> it to a real file on disk first -->
  <mappedresources>
    <mergemapper to="com/example/buildinfo.properties"/>
    <string encoding="ISO-8859-1"># this is a generated file, do not edit
      targetname=custom-build-1
    </string>
  </mappedresources>
</jar>
```

which you can then read in your main method

```
package com.example;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Properties buildInfo = new Properties();
    InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("buildinfo.properties");
    try {
      buildInfo.load(is);
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }

    System.out.println("Build target was " +
       buildInfo.getProperty("targetname", "<unknown>"));
  }
}
```

This should print

```
Build target was custom-build-1
```

Answer (score 1):

That sounds strange!

Usually you build with ant or maven. (or with exlipse)
But that is outside to your java code.

So you print the build target in the ant (or maven) skript.

In Ant:

```
<target name="jar">
    <echo>Building target: ${target}</echo>

...
</target>
```

Or do you mean getting the name of the jar file that is running the main():

```
File jarFile = new File
(org.classes.main.class.getProtectionDomain()
.getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
System.out.println(jarFile.getName());
```

Comment: I know we build it with ant. What I am looking for is,  can the program made to remember somehow , under which target it was built ?

Comment: And you want to print ou the target on the console while ant is building?

Comment: No No.  After the building is done, when the resulting JAR is called, I want to print the target

Comment: The target is a step in the build progress. The final result of th e building is one ore more jar files. They (usually) will not be called in the build dprocess. They will be called when you run the app. Do you want to print out the name of the jar file that is running?

Comment: Was that what you meant (see my update on printing the name of the jat file in main.

Comment: Lets say step 1 is building. Say building produces a Jar file. Say it was build with a target named 'custome-build-1'
Let say step 2 is calling the JAR file's main() function.
I want the step 2 to print the 'custome-build-1'

Comment: Then simply pass the name if the target as argument to main.